# What is the route for public access from within a private subnet given in this diagram-example provided by AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

[cite] Amazon Virtual Cloud - Kindle Book, location 607

For this question, please note the boxed (red) text that indicates that instances from within the private subnet can send requests to the internet.

Q: Where is the route path for instances in the "private" subnet to get Internet access? Wouldn't it need its own gateway for that?

[image: example page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instances in private subnet access the internet through NAT and then through Internet Gateway (IGW):

```
private instance ---> NAT ---> IGW ---> Internet
```

Comment: private instance route table sends 0.0.0.0/0 traffic to NAT gateway (that is on public subnet) -> NAT gateway sends 0.0.0./0 traffic to internet gateway -> then to internet

Comment: Thanks, so routing can make multiple hops? Would it be more explicit to place a NAT GW inside the private subnet or use an Egress only GW?

Comment: @SteveJ NAT must be in public subnet, because it has to access IGW. You can't change that behavior.